# how to run batik sqiggle jar on windows

Tags: java, windows, svg, batik

I am working on a project where I have to use svg batik for parsing and squiggle for viewing the svg image. I am trying to run batik squiggle jar (`batik-squiggle.jar`) from windows command prompt like below :

```
java -jar batik-squiggle.jar -font-size 10 D:/svg/Hammer.svg
```

But I am getting the following error

> "Unable to access jarfile batik-squiggle.jar"

I tried to to execute the command with ""(double quotes) also like below

```
java -jar batik-squiggle.jar -font-size 10 "D:/svg/Hammer.svg"
```

But still getting same error. What should I do to get the viewer as like mentioned in http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/tools/browser.html - Viewing SVG documents section.

Comment: does `dir batik-squiggle.jar` show the file?

Comment: D:\Sharan\Task\4.JavaFx3D Viwer\BackupCode>dir batik-squiggle.jar
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is 2470-74EE

 It Shows as below Directory of D:\Sharan\Task\4.JavaFx3D Viwer\BackupCode

21-03-2013  13:19           553,671 batik-squiggle.jar
               1 File(s)        553,671 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  748,628,955,136 bytes free

Comment: @stefan hegny, Thanks for your reply, It shows as the above, when i do the "dir batik-squiggle.jar".

Comment: okay, what does happen when you double-click it in the explorer? I suppose the file is somehow in use, reboot might do good

Comment: @StefanHegny, I rebooted the machine and tried accessing the jar by double-click, but it throws "A JNI Error has occured" in a popup.

Comment: @StefanHegny, I can able to access the jar by following the steps in this link([link]http://ubuntudigest.blogspot.in/2012/08/how-to-setup-squiggle-browser-add.html).